# z3: converting a formula to dnf

Tags: z3

is there a built in method in Z3 python to convert a formula to DNF ?  I would imagine applying some strategies or tactics to do so.

Also, how do I "create" an expression, for example,  if I have the variables

`op=Or, arg1=True, arg2=False`

I want to create the expression Or(True,False) using op,arg1,arg2.  I could do something like

```
if op.name == 'or':   Or(arg1,arg2)   
elif op.name == 'and':  And(arg1,arg2)
...
```

but is there a better way ?

Also,  I recall there's a file in Z3 that lists the sort code, e.g.  2L is Z3_INT_SORT, what's its name ?

Comment: I figured out the create an expression part,   I can just simply call  op(arg1,arg2)  ..

Comment: You may want a full-blown parser, depending upon what you want to accomplish, instead of switching on operation names.

I didn't understand the last part: "I recall there's a file in Z3 that lists the sort code, e.g. 2L is Z3_INT_SORT, what's its name ?"  What is 2L?

Comment: 2L is the identifier for int sort in Z3.    There's a file in Z3 that tells you what these identifiers are (e.g.  2L correspond to Z3_INT_SORT) and I want to know where that file is.

Comment: Okay, look at the bottom of the python documentation (under the "Data" section): http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/z3.html

You can see Z3_INT_SORT declared as 2 there.  You might also check this source file (z3consts.py):

http://z3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/1cfe6e477a3d#python%2fz3consts.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this answer for how to convert to DNF: [How to convert a formula to Disjunctive Normal Form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11599230/how-to-convert-a-formula-to-disjunctive-normal-form)

As a related note, see this answer on how to convert to CNF: [Convert formula to CNF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10992531/convert-formula-to-cnf)

These examples are in the SMT format, here they are in z3py: http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/ik4

Comment: the CNF method given introduces auxilary variables so not exactly what I want.  I want the new formula to consist of just variables from the input formula.